# Changing the font style in an android keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad, android-input-method

I'm developing an android keyboard that is based on soft keyboard. What I want is to change the keys label textstyle ex. (bold, shadowColor, innerShadow, color, etc...).

How to do that?

Comment: can you tell us what have you tried until now ?

Comment: i tried to use android:textStyle and textSize on the xml input layout and on the xml keyboard keys. anything doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Change  keys Label:

```
mQwertyKeyboard.getKeys().get(2).label="Label Name";
```

Change keys Font & Bold:

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"avanish.ttf");
    List<Keyboard.Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for (Keyboard.Key key : keys) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTypeface(tf);
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + key.width,
                        key.y + key.height, paint);
    }
}
```

and Other things like shadowColor, innerShadow etc change using res/values/styles in android.
So learn more about the styles.

Thanks.